# OpenVPN connect to serwer with user and password without cert

Tags: openvpn

I have never used OpenVPN before that is why I am newbie. I am using Linux Ubuntu 20.04.

I get a server IP with port, user and password. Is it possible to connect to that server using openvpn command or maybe create some config file? I have installed the "network-manager-openvpn" plugin. There I have three options: OpenVPN, PPTP or import from file. When I chose the PPTP the connection it is failed, when OpenVPN I can not save the config because the ca file is required.

Is there anyone who had the same/similar problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: @Alejandro IMO this question is strongly connected with programming. I need it to connect with server and update/upload/download a programming project. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: If someone find this post. I have installed a forticlient and It works. Unfortunately I can not find solutions for openvpn.